# Configuring Salesforce identity & Google apps

Tags: google-apps, identity

I am trying to setup sso between Salesforce and gmail and have followed all the steps listed in Salesforce Identity implementation guide.

But when I click on Gmail connected apps button I get a blank screen, Below are my settings and the blank screen, can anyone here help and let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]